# Meteor 0.8.0 fails to install atmosphere packages

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I just upgraded to Meteor 0.8.0 and now installing packages with meteorite fails. I tried a lot, including uninstalling and reinstalling Meteor and Meteorite from scratch. I am running meteor on a Mac with 10.9.2.

I just create a fresh app

```
mrt create myapp
cd myapp
```

and add some random atmosphere package

```
myapp add aws-sdk
```

and I get this error, no matter which package I try to install:

```
smart.json changed.. installing from smart.json
✓ aws-sdk
    tag: https://github.com/peerlibrary/meteor-aws-sdk.git#v1.5.1.1

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/lib/dependencies/package.js:106
    throw('Could not locate package.js within path ' + self.source.packagePa
                                                   ^
Could not locate package.js within path /Users/Me/.meteorite/packages/aws-sdk/peerlibrary/meteor-aws-sdk/63efa4ebbe9986bd875f69d5fdf3248c5c44159e
my-mac-pro:myapp Me$
```

After that, the following line for removing the failing package produces exactly the same error:

```
mrt remove aws-sdk
```

Thank you very much for any hint!

Answer (score 5):

Ah. Forgot I already knew the answer to the problem, just did not recognize the problem. This error seems to be a rephrased version of the error "unable to clone repo xyz" in the old version and comes from inappropriate permissions. The answer is reinstalling only meteorite and fixing the permissions:

```
sudo mrt uninstall
sudo mrt uninstall --system
sudo chown -R `whoami` ~/.npm
sudo -H npm install -g meteorite
```

Hope that helps anybody, if not i'll probably just delete the question sooner or later!

Comment: I had a problem after running this that was resolved by `mrt uninstall --system`, so probably shouldn't install it in the first place.